# Size of google Charts in modal html javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

im working with modal in html and javascript and I want to custom size of my plot. My google chart:

```
 function drawChartVector(vector) {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(vector);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
        vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

and my modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
                <div id="chart_div"  style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

But when I show:

The modal ajust of size but chart not.
[image]

Comment: I think you should try calling `drawChartVector(vector)` after the modal is shown. Because `display: none;` elements will always have 0 width/height.

Comment: Yes , thanks so much , frist I call modal and later chart , and works  modal.style.display = "block";
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartVector(data,name));